# Ember route with quotes deprecation warning

Tags: ember.js

I recently upgraded to Ember RC7.  I have some bootstrap tabs which map to some child routes using 'linkTo' in the following way:

```
{{#linkTo page.tab1 this href=false tagName=li}}{{#linkTo page.tab1}}tab 1{{/linkTo}}{{/linkTo}}
{{#linkTo page.tab2 this href=false tagName=li}}{{#linkTo page.tab2}}tab 2{{/linkTo}}{{/linkTo}}
```

This has worked with no problem until RC7.  I now get the following warning:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:364
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.7 ember.js:364
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js:364
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 ember.js:364
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:364
render combined-scripts.js:995
DEPRECATION: You provided a quoteless destination route parameter of page.tab1 to the linkTo helper. Soon, this will perform a property lookup, rather than be treated as a string. To get rid of this warning, wrap form.index in quotes. To opt in to this new behavior, set ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS = true
        at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:28036:15)
        at Object.anonymous (http://localhost:9001/scripts/compiled-templates.js:225:72)
        at Handlebars.VM.template (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js:2212:33)
        at Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.render (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:16826:16)
        at Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend._renderToBuffer (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:15767:10)
        at Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._renderToBuffer (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:17406:23)
        at superWrapper [as _renderToBuffer] (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:1082:16)
        at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:15748:19)
        at Object.Ember.Instrumentation.instrument (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/ember/ember.js:1465:20)
```

I tried putting page.tab1 & page.tab2 in quotes, but then my links do not work properly, it's as if the that breaks the 2 way binding.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

**UPDATE**
added a JSBin example:
Notice that as you click on the 'Next' button the link urls do not update to the new item, even though the name field does.  i.e. click the next button and the url will remain /item/1 even though it should be /item/2

http://jsbin.com/atazuy/22/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is unrelated to your use of quoting. The problem you're having is that your inner `{{linkTo}}`s don't match your outer ones. In your example you are providing a second `this` parameter to the `{{linkTo}}` in the outer context but not in the inner one. In this case `this` is the controller, not the model, which is causing you problems. See http://jsbin.com/atazuy/29 for a working version.

Comment: fwiw [this soon-to-be-merged PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3193) will make it possible to just use `this` as a `linkTo` param and have expected binding behavior work

Comment: @Peter Your jsbin doesn't work, notice how as you click the next button the link does not update the path correctly.

Comment: Confirm on Peter's jsbin not working. This one does though: http://jsbin.com/atazuy/29/edit

Comment: @AlexanderWallaceMatchneer yours is better, but it still has an issue... it's 1 behind... i.e.  when i first load the page the link is #, then when i click the next button the url is #/item/1 (it should be #/item/2) if I click it again the link is #item/2 but should be #/item/3 etc.

Comment: hmm, i take that back, now it seems to be right... (scratching head)... let me play with it a little more :)

Comment: ok from what I can tell that works @AlexanderWallaceMatchneer if you want the bounty create a seperate answer w/ your jsbin and i'll give it to you :)

Comment: I'll just let Peter update and he can take it and babysit my kid some day or something